# Detect Orientation Change in React Web App Safari

Tags: reactjs, mobile-safari, screen-orientation

I'm writing a React Web App for Android and iPhone. I'm trying to get updates on orientation changes in the device. In Chrome/Firefox or most other browsers I can do:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', this.orientationChange);

orientationChange()
{
    console.log('info-view: orientation change detected ' + window.screen.orientation.type);

    try {
        screenOrientation = window.screen.orientation.type;
    } catch (error) {}
}
```

But that doesn't work in Safari because it `orientationchange` is simply not supported. Even though the callback is executed when orientation is changed `window.screen.orientation` is `undefined`.

As far as I've looked there isn't a way to get a callback  for orientation change in Safari. I've been at this problem for more than 2 weeks now and I really need any kind of workaround/solution for this that might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out even though the usual `window.screen.orientation` is `undefined` in safari [`window.orientation - (deprecated)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientation) tells the orientation in degrees as 0, 90, -90 and 180.

I know it is not a perfect answer since this feature is deprecated but it is the (Only) one that works on Safari, if anyone knows a better way to detect orientation in Safari mobile web then please do share.